# How to get part of the first word in a string of multiple words using ksh

Tags: string, ksh, split

My string is of this format.

```
/abc/def/ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx
```

Or

```
/abc/def/ghi.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx
```

Or

```
./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx
```

Or

```
./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx
```

I want to extract out only

```
ghi.klm_nop.out
```

or  `ghi.out`

Whats my best bet using ksh.

I am trying a few things
like

```
str='/abc/def/ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx '
echo ${str##/*/}
```

But this does not work when where is / in the words after.
So i first want to get the first word and then do something like above.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `read` in a `while` loop to get the first word, then `basename` to strip off the path:

```
while read -r path rest; do
    file=$(basename "$path")
    echo "$file"
done <<END
/abc/def/ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx 
/abc/def/ghi.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx 
./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx 
./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx 
END
```

```
ghi.klm_nop.out
ghi.out
ghi.klm_nop.out
ghi.klm_nop.out
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution closest to what you did (and perhaps fastest), is

```
echo "Internal"
for str in "/abc/def/ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx" \
        "/abc/def/ghi.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx " \
        "./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx " \
        "./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx "; do
   tmp=${str%% *}
   echo "${tmp##*/}"
done
```

With a lot patience you can do a lot with `sed`:

```
echo "Sed"
for str in "/abc/def/ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx" \
        "/abc/def/ghi.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx " \
        "./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx " \
        "./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx "; do
   echo "${str}" | sed -e 's/ .*//' -e 's#.*/##'
done
```

And when you are willing the learn awk the next mixture is an option:

```
echo "Awk"
for str in "/abc/def/ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx" \
        "/abc/def/ghi.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx " \
        "./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx " \
        "./ghi.klm_nop.out abc def /abc/mno xxx xxx "; do
   echo "${str%% *}"| awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
done
```